# JavaScript if statement does not work

Tags: javascript

I have an if statement in JS. when I set the value a == 50, it does not say a is equal to 50. instead it say a is greater than 50. [How should I fix this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jZoj.png)

Comment: ; in if conditional statement and what is b?

Comment: How is this even supposed to work with a nested if statement inside `a < 50`

Comment: Also please paste your code into the question (with proper formatting), adding images with code is not a good practice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo in this line:

```
if (a == b); {
//         ^
```

Remove the semicolon `;` after the if-condition:

```
if (a == b) {
```

There are two problems with the above if:

1. `b` seems to be undeclared.
2. Your alert says *a is equal to 50*. But it will never happens inside the `if (a < 50) {`.

---

You should use:

```
var b = 50;

if (a < b) {
    alert ("a is less than " + b);
} else if (a == b) {
    alert ("a is equal to " + b);
} else {
    alert ("a is greater than " + b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is wrong just change the you first `if` condition

```
if(a<=50){
}
```

and also remove the `;` from the if condition. after that you are ready to go.

if you check the condition like this `a<50` so the if condition block only execute when `a` value is `49` or less than so you never get the message like the `a is equal to 50`.

Answer (score 0):

if condition format is `if(cond) {}` ! no semicolon. Try with ternary also to see how it work ..

```
var a = 50;
alert(a < 50 ? "a is less than 50" : (a == 50) ? "a is equal to 50" : " a is greater than 50");
```

Ternary work as

```
condition ? true : false ;
```